# How to add julia file support to the Jupyterlab editor?

Tags: julia, jupyter-lab

How to add to the Jupyterlab launcher the option to create a text file with `.jl` extension via an icon?

For instance to write Python `.py`file in the Jupyter editor, there exists a neat jupyter extension: https://github.com/jtpio/jupyterlab-python-file

Any equivalent for Julia, or any work around?

Comment: You could fork that and change 2-3 lines of code, and that would be about it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following the comment above, I adapted thanks to the original author the `jupyterlab-python-file` npm extension to `jupyterlab-julia-file`.

To install it please do:

```sh
jupyter labextension install @arcticsnow/jupyterlab-julia-file
```

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2022: this is no longer needed, the icon is automatically added if you have Julia kernel installed.